# how to create trigger in SQL server using two tables to find stock quantity in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table sales and purchase. I want to create a trigger which stores final quantity in stock table by subtracting sales table sold quantity from purchase table.

There is kikkat as a name n quantity are 10, 15 respectively and both quantities should be subtracted from purchase quantity table and it should be saved in the stock table.

Here is my [table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106034/how-to-create-trigger-in-sql-server-using-two-tables-to-find-stock-quantity)

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server as dbms?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using sql server , so instead creating trigger I would suggest you to create a new column in purchase table which will be computed column.

Before creating it create a scalar function which will accept productname or productid and returns int , inside it write query to find total from sales table for a that particular row (by passing productname or id) and substract it from purchase table's quantity for that product.

If purchase table can contain multiple entries for a particular product then create separate table "Stock" and have columns as ID, ProductName\Id, stockQuantity (which will be computed column as explained above).